# Unpacking Sympy variables from dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, arguments, sympy

I am making a program to do some calculations for my Microeconomics class. Since there are some ways of working depending on the problem I am given, I have created a class. The class parses an Utility function and a 'mode' from the command line and calls a function or another depending on the mode.
Since every function uses the same variables I initiate them in `__init__()`:

```
self.x = x = Symbol('x')  # Variables are initiated
self.y = y = Symbol('y')
self.Px, self.Py, self.m = Px, Py, m = Symbol('Px'), Symbol('Py'), Symbol('m')
```

I need a local definition to successfully process the function. Once the function is initiated through `sympify()` I save it as an instance variable:

```
self.function = sympify(args.U)
```

Now I need to pass the variables `x,yPx,Py,m` to the different functions. This is where I have the problem. As I want a local definition I could simply `x=self.x` with all the variables. I would need to repeat this in every piece of code which isn't really sustainable. Another option is to pass all the variables as arguments.

But since I'm using a dictionary to choose which function to call depending on the mode this would mean I have to pass the same arguments for every function, whether I use them or not.

So I have decided to create a dictionary such as:

```
variables = {          #A dictionary of variables is initiated
        'x':self.x,
        'y':self.y,
        'Px':self.Px,
        'Py':self.Py,
        'm':self.m
        }
```

This dictionary is initiated after I declare the variables as sympy `Symbols`. What I would like is to pass this dictionary in an unpacked form to every function. This way i would only need `**kwargs` as an argument and I could use the variables I want.

What I want is something like this:

```
a = 3
arggs = {'a' = a}
def f(**kwargs):return a+1
f(**args)
```

This returns 4. However when I pass my dictionary as an argument I get a non-defined 'x' or 'y' variables error. It can't be an scope issue because all the variables have been initiated for all the instance.

Here is my code calling the function:

```
 self.approaches[self.identification][0](**self.variables)
 def default(self, **kwargs):
     solutions = dict()
     self.MRS = S(self.function.diff(x) / self.function.diff(y))   # This line provokes the exception
```

What's my error?

<sub>PS: Some information may be unclear. English is not my main language. Apologies in advance.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Python doesn't quite work like that. When you use `**kwargs`, the only variable this assigns is the variable `kwargs`, which is a dictionary of the keyword arguments.  In general, there's no easy way to inject names into a function's local namespace, because of the way locals namespaces work. There are ways to do it, but they are fairly hacky.

The easiest way to make the variables available without having to define them each time is to define them at the module level. Generally speaking, this is somewhat bad practice (it really *does* belong on the class), but since SymPy Symbols are immutable and defined entirely by their name (and assumptions if you set any), it's just fine to set

```
Px, Py, m = symbols("Px Py m")
```

at the module level (i.e., above your class definition), because even if some other function defines its own `Symbol("Px")`, SymPy will consider it equal to the `Px` you defined from before.

In general, you can play somewhat fast and loose with immutable objects in this way (and all SymPy objects are immutable) because it doesn't really matter if an immutable object gets replaced with a second, equal object. It would matter, if, say, you had a list (a mutable container) because it would make a big difference if it were defined on the module level vs. the class level vs. the instance level.

Comment: Whats the "hacky" way of doing this for an unknown specified amount of variables which may vary from being normal symbols like x,y,z to m_g or v_B?

Comment: @imranal the reason it's hacky is that in Python a local namespace (the namespace of a function) is determined statically. So it doesn't make sense to define variables dynamically because you always know when the function is compiled exactly what variable names are used in it. Global (module-level) namespaces do not work like this, and it's in fact quite easy to inject variable names into `globals()` (the SymPy `var` function does this automatically). But again, if you are statically using some specific variables in a script, then just define those variables exactly.